# Understanding asyncio in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I've been having a hard time understanding Python's asyncio module and how to not block on asynchronous calls. For instance, given this code snippet:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import async_timeout

async def fetch(session, url):
    with async_timeout.timeout(10):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()

async def main(loop):
    print(1)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        html = await fetch(session, 'http://python.org')
        print(html)
    print(2)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

I would expect, similar to how this would work in Javascript, the output to be

```
1
2
<!doctype html>
<...>
```

Instead, the function prints 1, blocks until it gets back the html, then prints 2. Why does it block, and how / can I avoid the blocking? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
html = await fetch(session, 'http://python.org')
```

this means - wait until getting a response from fetch, Or in other word's it's blocking the **current** coroutine until the fetch coroutine return's the response text.

To make things simpler:

- The fetch operation by itself isn't blocking, only the await.
- The await is blocking only for the current coroutine, not the thread.
- Like [vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2846140/vincent) said, calling the operation by itself doesn't do anything (we don't start the fetching process)

from [asyncio documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html)

> Calling a coroutine does not start its code running – the coroutine
>   object returned by the call doesn’t do anything until you schedule its
>   execution. There are two basic ways to start it running: call await
>   coroutine or yield from coroutine from another coroutine (assuming the
>   other coroutine is already running!), or schedule its execution using
>   the ensure_future() function or the AbstractEventLoop.create_task()
>   method.

And a fix (for getting the desired output):

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import async_timeout


async def fetch(session, url):
    with async_timeout.timeout(10):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()


async def main(loop):
    print(1)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        future = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(session, 'http://python.org')) # we start the fetch process
        print(2)
        html = await future # we wait for getting the fetch response
        print(html)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

Comment: Calling the `fetch` coroutine doesn't schedule the fetch operation, and it doesn't return a future. You have to use [asyncio.ensure_future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=async#asyncio.ensure_future) in order to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my answer, I edited my code and added additional explanation.

Comment: Thanks, this explanation was very helpful. So, if I did want to *start* the coroutine without blocking execution of the rest of the function... I would effectively need to await an asyncio.sleep(0) after the asyncio.ensure_future?? Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: using asyncio.ensure_future start the coroutine and dosn't block the rest of the function

Comment: @etlsh I guess what I mean is that, if I add an `await asyncio.sleep(0)` just after the `asyncio.ensure_future`, it will actually start executing the coroutine before 2 prints. Otherwise, it won't even begin until after the 2 prints, correct?

Comment: yes, you need to do some sort of async operation (and give the event-loop time to schedule things)

Answer (score 3):

To understanding asyncio in python 3.6 `async def` style I suggest you to run this simple example:

```
import asyncio
import time

def write(msg):
    print(msg, flush=True)

async def say1():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    write("Hello 1!")

async def say2():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    write("Hello 2!")

write("start")
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
    say1(),
    say2()
))
write("exit")

loop.close()
```

Source: https://maketips.net/tip/146/parallel-execution-of-asyncio-functions  See link for detailed explanations of this code with call diagram .